# Xamarin.Forms - what backend solution should I choose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, wcf, xamarin.forms

I am in the process of creating a Xamarin.Forms mobile app via Visual Studio. I was looking into finding a solution for the backend (server) that the app would need to communicate with. I am aware that one can use cloud services like AWS / Azure or host a webservice that use technologies like ASMX or WCF. The current requirements for the app are:

1) The app users register and sign in using their email address as an ID.
2) Signed in app users will receive 2 text messages a day (from the server), no longer than a sentence each.

So in terms of raw data transfer amount, I don't imagine a lot of backend bandwidth would be required. Despite this low data requirement, should I still use a cloud service like AWS / Azure for the backend? Or should I use a webservice backend like ASMX / WCF and find a company that hosts such web services?

What would be the best back end approach for starting out with such a small scale app such as this one?

Comment: What is your reason to assume that Azure would not be worth it for the low transfer amount? If at any rate possible I will never go back to VM or Bare Metal hosting and always use Azure in future, since it svaes you so much trouble. BTW, I assume that the question will be considered off-topic and closed (please see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: I have tried azure though in my struggles to grasp the fundamentals of mobile app development I have now gone past the 1 month trial period without having had enough time to focus on azure itself. What I did not like about azure was the fact that my account was charged over 50 USD for that month (out of the 160 free USD they give upon subscription).   
I hardly had any data transfer at all (just a basic hello world app) that ran on it for a few weeks with only me sending and receiving a total of some 50 texts.  What are you rthoughts on AWS vs Azure?

Comment: It's not solely about data transfer. If you have a functions app and set the billing to *consumption based*, you will only be charged the actual runtime of the functions. Considering the free quota of a functions app, for an app that is not used that much, you'll only have to pay for the storage, which would sum up to about 4 USD a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest Azure Functions in consumption plan. Azure in general is the lowest price, and in the consumption plan you will pay only the request that you actually use and the database(~$7?). Plus, you have a million of free requests per month, that I like to use for development/prototyping.

So, it worth, 'cause its very scalable.

Comment: @Paul Kertscher / @ Alan Jones

Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction.  I was loath to have to figure out how to host my own server and I had no idea about the functions plan in Azure which is pretty much exactly what I need to get started with this small scale app.

The timing of this input is great since I had just started with AWS but preferred Azure as the latter is part of the whole microsoft world which I am more familiar with as a C# developer using Visual Studio..